# Patch Function in Shim Interface for golang

Tags: rest, go, hyperledger-fabric, shim, glide-golang

I am using hyperledger fabric services via golang with the shim package.

It has GetState, PutState, DelState.
Get is used to retrieve a data linked to a key.
Put is used to create/update the body of a data linked to a key

I want to ask, how will I use the PATCH REST API for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PATCH-like verb for making a partial update for the value of a key ... it is all or nothing.

Comment: So, basically we can only use POST,PUT,GET,DELETE only for hyperledger fabric?

Comment: You can PutState (create / update) or GetState (get).  There are a few other verbs for querying data as well (range queries, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)